# LARAVEL: export row database in structure excel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, export

It's posible to export record database with structure Excel like that, from web

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl and refer to documentation on how to export and use it in Laravel.